# Reading files from S3 concurrently

Tags: c#, multithreading, amazon-s3

I am calling the below method to get files from `S3`. I have a list of file paths in a collection. I call the below method inside `Parallel.Foreach` loop. The method `addRecords()` of container is thread safe and ensures that only one thread enters the critical section. The code skips some of the files and the returned result has less records than expected.

```
Parallel.ForEach(fileListAll, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20 }, (currentFile) =>
                {
                    string RecordsRaw = _AmazonS3.GetFileFromS3(currentFile);

                    Container.AddRecords(RecordsRaw);
                });



public string GetFileFromS3(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                string ResponseData = null;
                GetObjectRequest Request = new GetObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = _AWSConfiguration.S3BucketName,
                    Key = filePath
                };
                using (GetObjectResponse response = _AmazonS3Client.GetObject(Request))
                using (Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    ResponseData = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ResponseData))
                {
                    return ResponseData;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Removed the code for brevity
            }
            return null;
        }
```

I am not sure how can I change `GetFileFromS3()` method so that it can be called by multiple threads while still maintaining concurrency.

Please bear with as this might be a basic question but I am struggling from 2 days to get this working correctly.

Comment: *"the returned result has less records than expected"* - Note that `GetFileFromS3()` has no effect on number of records added to the `Container`, it only determines whether *file content* or `null` is added to the `Container`. If there is a problem, it is probably in the `AddRecords()` - ensure that it is really *thread-safe* and doesn't handle `null`s or duplicities differently. Also note that catching and silently swallowing all exceptions (in `GetFileFromS3`) is bad practice, because it doesn't let you detect any error (that is likely to occur from time to time during network operations).

Comment: @Ňuf Thanks for the reply. The code inside `AddRecords()` works fine as I tested that independently. I removed the code inside the catch block so as to simplify the question as the code inside catch was not relevant it would unnecessary add to the length of the question.